# In sepsis what therapies are used to reduce the over-reaction of the immune system?

Tags: immune-system, inflammation, fungal-infection, blood-clotting

Sepsis is initiated by infection (usually bacteria or fungi) but the main symptoms arise from over-reaction to the infection by our immune system leading to inappropriate levels of inflammation and also blood clotting. Organ damage follows. So, apart from giving antibiotics, what other therapies do physicians give to reduce the over-reaction of the immune system, the clotting and to protect organs?

Answer (score 1):

for now there is no specific immunotherapy for the treatment sepsis (defined as sepsis-3.0); the main treatment for severe sepsis is supportive in the intensive care unit. some medicine such as ulinastatin and thymosin α1 https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26517783 may be effective but with low level of evidence.